How to mock IObjectMapper with AutoMapper implementation manually in unit tests
Let's say I have a repository called OrderRepository that reaches out to the database via the OrderingDbContext, and uses IObjectMapper to map between domain and database entity models:
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    private readonly OrderingDbContext _orderingDbContext;
    private readonly IObjectMapper _objectMapper;

    public OrderRepository(OrderingDbContext orderingDbContext, IObjectMapper objectMapper)
    {
        _orderingDbContext = orderingDbContext;
        _objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var orderDbEntities = await _orderingDbContext.Orders
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        return _objectMapper.Map<IEnumerable<OrderDbEntity>, IEnumerable<Order>>(orderDbEntities);
    }
}

public class OrderingDbContext : AbpDbContext<OrderingDbContext>
{
    ...
}

And this is using the modular approach so we have
[DependsOn(
    typeof(DomainModule),
    typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule),
    typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkCorePostgreSqlModule)
)]
public class DatabaseEfCoreModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceconfigurationContext context)
    {
        ...

        Configure<AbpAutoMapperOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AddProfile<DbEntityToDomainModelProfile>(validate: true);
        });

        context.Services.AddAbpDbContext<OrderingDbContext>();
        ...
    }
}

You see IObjectMapper is using the default AutoMapper implementation, and DbEntityToDomainModelProfile is an AutoMapper profile class:
using AutoMapper;
...

public class DbEntityToDomainModelProfile : Profile
{
    public DbEntityToDomainModelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<OrderDbEntity, Order>();
        ...
    }
}

So far so good ...
Now when I am writing unit tests for this repository,
using Xunit;
using NSubstitute;
...

public class OrderRepositoryTests
{
    public class GetAllAsync
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task WhenThereIsNoOrder_ShouldReturnEmptyList()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockDbContext = Substitute.For<OrderingDbContext>();
            ...

            var mockObjectMapper = Substitute.For<IObjectMapper>();
            // --> !!!
            // --> !!!

            var sut = new OrderRepository(mockDbContext, mockObjectMapper);

            // Act
            var orders = await sut.GetAllAsync()

            // Assert
            ...
        }
    }
}

// --> !!! there how can I mock IObjectMapper with AutoMapper implementation manually (here I am using NSubstitute)?

One "workaround" I can think of is to mock IObjectMapper Map method specially for each test:
[Fact]
public async Task WhenThereIsNoOrder_ShouldReturnEmptyList()
{
    // Arrange
    ...
    var mockObjectMapper = Substitute.For<IObjectMapper>();
    mockObjectMapper.Map<IEnumerable<OrderDbEntity>, IEnumerable<Order>>(Args.Any<...>())
        .Returns(new List<Order>
        {
            ...
        });
}

But the "drawback" on this is that I can't really use the existing mapping profile with the tests. And since I am sure I am returning a list of domain models for sure (since I hard code them in the test), it almost seems like there is no point to write unit tests to test this repository.
I tried to look up ABP's documentation. It only says if you define your module class that uses DependsOn(typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule)), it will "magically" work. But here in my unit tests, I don't want to load up the ABP framework there (I am not doing integration testing). All I am looking for is a way to manually set IObjectMapper's implementation.

Would it be an option to assign it an actual AutoMapper mapper with the appropriate config? I don't see a benefit in faking one that in the end needs to replicate the original.

Other question would be: what's the unit? If you just want to verify calls being made, then the fake mapper doesn't actually have to do the mapping, right?

I don't think you should provide a real implementation of AutoMapper for your tests. That's not a unit test either. Your GetAllAsync returns whatever the automapper.Map() method returns, so you just need to provide a mock value for the return of .Map() and assert that the return value of your GetAllAsync is the same as the .Map() method's return value.

@quyentho: if I just provide a mock value for the Map() method, of course it would the same as the return value of GetAllAsync() wouldn't it? I don't see much value on a test like that...

@Fildor: I can get the actual AutoMapper profile and create an AutoMapper's Mapper in the tests without problems. The issue is that the sut takes ABP's IObjectMapper, not the AutoMapper's IMapper.

@Fildor: "what's the unit" - that got me thinking for a while. I was thinking that the unit was GetAllAsync, and the scenarios would be 1) if there is no orders in the database/dbContext, it should return empty list 2) if there are few orders in the database/dbContext, it should return a few. I was trying to fix the variable IObjectMapper, having it do the actual mappings, while trying to mock the other variable OrderDbContext.Orders. Maybe you're right. They both are the dependents of the units I am trying to test. Maybe I should just mock both of them, which results no much to test lol

Automapper can be treated as a dependency just like a DbContext instance. The result from AutoMapper isn't directly relevant because you ultimately specify the expected value of the test. If a bug in AutoMapper causes its .Map() method to differ from your expected value, would you trust AutoMapper and change your expectation, or would you switch to a different mapping library / implementation?

My five cents here would be to mock the mapper completely for unit tests, but do have integration tests that assert that you have always valid mapper configuration.

@Prolog: Yep I think that's the way to go.
